# Ubercart cart layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I've an issue with the Ubercart cart layout in Drupal. See this image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/cart.png

The column products and the products name are not aligned, for some reason.

I cannot fix it with only css, because I cannot align all columns, if I hide elements, or change their size.

I'm looking for the cart php template, but I cannot find it.

thanks

Comment: no, it is not a modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column will be aligned if you add images to your products.
See uc_cart_view_table function in uc_cart.module